# "Index" page to display all items associated with current_user using '.where' but result is ActiveRecord, and I need to run each do on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

Sorry for the long title, I wanted to make sure I was being as specific as possible. This is my first question so please be patient!

I am building an index page that displays all the items in the consultations model that are associated with the current user. This used to be easy when I set @`consultations = Consultation.where(user_id: current_user.id)` in my controller. However, because consultations should be able to have more than one consultant assigned to each one, I changed the `Consultation.user_id` field to be a string array (I wasn't able to change to an integer array). I also connected the User and Consultation models via has_and_belongs_to_many and a join table.

I am now trying to query them with `@consultation = Consultation.where {|a| a.user_id == ['current_user.id']}` so that I can display all consultations in which the `Consultation.user_id` array contains the `current_user.id`.
This works as expected in pry, but on the actual view page I'm getting an error: `NoMethodError: undefined method /'each/' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x007f82c23fe840>`.

I understand that this is to be expected, since `.where` returns an ActiveRecord, which does not support methods such as `each do`, which is what I'm using on the index page to show all the consultations.

Any idea on how I can properly display all the consultations associated with the `current_user.id`? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like

```
@consultations = current_user.consultations
```

use associations instead of query

**BTW**

```
@consultation = Consultation.where {|a| a.user_id == ['current_user.id']}
```

this will not work because `'current_user.id'` is string, it isn't `id`

it means that  you try find all `consultation`s where `user_id == 'current_user.id'`.

Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Thanks for your answer- I think that the string/integer mis-matching is causing your first suggestion to fail though. It returns an empty array. Do you think it might just be easiest to create a new column for user_id, but make it an integer and an array from the beginning?

Comment: `@consultations = current_user.consultations` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, user_id needs to be an array I think, since each consultation can have multiple consultants.

Comment: It's the same consultation though, so does that mean that it needs to be entered multiple times, once for each consultant/user_id?

Comment: I can't understand what you need, if you need all consultation for current_user, take a look at my suggestion

Comment: Sorry, `@consultations = current_user.consultations` does not work. It returns an empty array. Perhaps because Consultation.user_id is a string array and User.id is an integer?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a many-to-many relationship between consultants and clients.  You can solve this by having a join table in the middle that holds both the client_id and the consultant_id.  This would be a 3rd model to the consultant model and client models that you already have.  You shouldn't try to store arrays as fields in ActiveRecord.  ActiveRecord is just helping you organize data that is being written to a database.

Once you have a join table with both foreign_id's you can easily set up has_many relationships for both the client and consultants and then a has_may_through association.  Then you won't need to worry about any #where calls because you can just call the associations.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the syntax where you pass a block to `where` is something that you've just made up. Because no actual arguments are passed to `where` you don't get an `ActiveRecord::Relation`

You could change relationship between consultation and users to be has many through. If that join model was called assignments, then you could write a query such as

```
Consultation.joins(:assignments).where(assignments: {user_id: current_user.id})
```

If you keep your current approach with a user_id array column then, assuming this is Postgres, you can use the array query methods:

```
Consultation.where("user_id @> ARRAY[?]", current_user.id)
```